# Is this how a R-2R DAC for VGA should work?

Tags: dac, vga, r2r

I'm trying to wrap my head around if this is how a R-2R DAC should work. I say *should* for two reasons: (1) because I think I understand the theory behind the resistor ladder of subsequent voltage-dividing, and (2) because I [analysed the schematic](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/reference/pmod/pmodvga/pmodvga_sch.pdf?_ga=2.78920657.431990261.1577390851-488460386.1577390851) of a common VGA Pmod from Xilinx, which I would expect to be, well... correct...

So, let's start with the circuit:

[image]

With all bits on, this achieves a ~0.7V max, considering the 75 internal impedance of a VGA monitor. Now, I've broken down all the possible combinations and the resulting voltage:

[image]

... which, suffice to say, is not what I expected how this should behave. A perfect DAC would be linear. A gamma-corrected VGA DAC would possibly be a curve. But these deltas are all over the place.

---

So here are the questions: (1) am I interpreting something wrong? (2) Is this how this type of DAC supposed to work? (3) How can we improve over this design?

Comment: Rushing out. Basic concept looks OK. Impedance of you chain is a constant 540 Ohms but terminated in 75 Ohms. Haven't checked what that will do but have a look.

Comment: what happens if you use true R-2R ? ... 270 Ohms and 540 Ohms for example

Comment: Without doing the analysis, I think the problem is with the 75 ohm resistor.  Take that out and see what you get.  R-2R DAC implementations are meant to feed into a high impedance op amp; not a 75 ohm load.

Comment: @SteveSh: Not true. The R-2R DAC has constant output impedance, which means that it forms a simple voltage divider with any load. There is no adverse effect on linearity, etc.

Comment: See [How to calculate resistor values for a VGA DAC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/453377/11683).

Comment: @Dave Tweed: You're right.  I had forgotten that and had to go through a simple example.  That being the case, the 75 ohm resistor should not be causing the non-linear behavior shown.

Comment: @David Tweed:  I see what happened.  The circuit in the OP really isn't a R-2R ladder as used in a DAC because, as Justme pointed out, the switches really need to be a SPDT configuration, connecting the 2R resistors to 3.3V or GND.  The circuit OP shown does exhibit a output resistance that varies as the position of the (shown) SPST switches.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The bits you control are either On or Disconnected, while in general a R2R DAC input would be connected to 3V3 or 0V. Disconnecting changes the impedance. Try with SPDT switches.

Comment: Good pickup on the switches.  That tripped me up.

Comment: Damn... damn... damn... DAMN... How did I missed that!?!

Comment: The CMOS rail to rail outputs are already SPDT switches

Answer (score 4):

[This is how I would have made a 4 bit DAC on 5.000 V logic.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2089.03963197220334%2064%205%2050%0Ar%20112%20416%20160%20416%200%20100000%0Ar%20160%20352%20112%20352%200%20100000%0Ar%20112%20384%20160%20384%200%20100000%0Ar%20160%20352%20160%20320%200%2050000%0Ag%2096%20272%2096%20288%200%0Ar%20160%20384%20160%20416%200%2050000%0Ar%20160%20320%20112%20320%200%20100000%0A164%20-48%20320%2016%20320%200%204%205%205%205%205%20false%200%0Ag%20-48%20416%20-48%20432%200%0AR%20-48%20320%20-64%20336%201%202%20200%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Aw%20112%20320%2048%20320%202%0Aw%20112%20352%2048%20352%202%0Aw%20112%20384%2048%20384%202%0Aw%20112%20416%2048%20416%202%0Ar%20160%20352%20160%20384%200%2050000%0Aw%20160%20320%20256%20320%202%0Ar%20160%20320%20160%20272%200%201200000%0A403%20240%20240%20576%20464%200%2015_64_0_12546_4.499999999999999_0.0001_0_2_15_3%0Ar%20160%20416%20160%20448%200%20100000%0Ag%20160%20448%20160%20464%200%0Aw%20160%20272%2096%20272%200%0A)

16 levels from 0 to 4.5V
 300 mV per level. Then Buffer output as required.

[image]

1R= 50.00k
2R=100.00k
Term = 1.200M
Error = 0 with 300mV per step using trimmed Vcc.

**for 3.3V Logic  Term=1.6M then 0 to 3.00V max with exactly 200mV /step**

Comment: Then for a 8 bit DAC with 256 integer steps Term = 588k  http://tinyurl.com/rj4lckf